# Is gcc reordering my volatile variables?

Tags: gcc, optimization, arm, volatile, cortex-m

I am developping on an STM32F746 (ARM Cortex-M7) with the GNU ARM Toolchain (gcc 5.4.1) using FreeRTOS. I am using the following CFLAGS set:

```
-g -Werror -Wextra -O2  -fno-common -ffunction-sections -fmessage-length=0 -g -mcpu=cortex-m7 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv5-sp-d16 -fno-common -ffunction-sections -fmessage-length=0 -g -mcpu=cortex-m7 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv5-sp-d16
```

The following code shows '0' in the console as if the DMA controller was not powered on. Normally, writing RCC_AHB1ENR_DMA1EN in the AHB1ENR register power on the DMA controller.

```
/* *** Other peripheral configurations *** */
RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_DMA1EN;                                     
DMA1_Stream3->CR = DMA_SxCR_PL | DMA_SxCR_MINC |                        
        DMA_SxCR_TCIE | DMA_SxCR_TEIE | DMA_SxCR_DMEIE;
DEBUG_PRINTF("%x\r\n", DMA1_Stream3->CR);
```

But the following code is printing the good value of DMA1_Stream3->CR.

```
/* *** Other peripheral configurations *** */
RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_DMA1EN;
__asm__ __volatile__ ("" ::: "memory");                                     
DMA1_Stream3->CR = DMA_SxCR_PL | DMA_SxCR_MINC |                        
        DMA_SxCR_TCIE | DMA_SxCR_TEIE | DMA_SxCR_DMEIE;
DEBUG_PRINTF("%x\r\n", DMA1_Stream3->CR);
```

I never had to add those memory barriers for any other controllers so why do I have to do this for this one? I am thinking about either a load/store instructions reordering by GCC either a timing issue. I checked in errata sheet of the CPU (STM32F746) or datasheet but didn't find anything.

Here is the definition of the RCC structure:

```
typedef struct
{
    /* ... */
    __IO uint32_t AHB1ENR;
    /* ... */
} RCC_TypeDef;
```

And here is the definition of the DMA1_Stream3 structure type:

```
typedef struct                                                                  
{                                                                               
  __IO uint32_t CR;     /*!< DMA stream x configuration register      */        
  __IO uint32_t NDTR;   /*!< DMA stream x number of data register     */        
  __IO uint32_t PAR;    /*!< DMA stream x peripheral address register */        
  __IO uint32_t M0AR;   /*!< DMA stream x memory 0 address register   */        
  __IO uint32_t M1AR;   /*!< DMA stream x memory 1 address register   */        
  __IO uint32_t FCR;    /*!< DMA stream x FIFO control register       */        
} DMA_Stream_TypeDef;
```

__IO is defined as volatile.

Here is the assembly code generated for the function:

```
08003f4c <bsp_initSPIADIS>:
 8003f4c:       4956            ldr     r1, [pc, #344]  ; (80040a8 <bsp_initSPIADIS+0x15c>)
 8003f4e:       4a57            ldr     r2, [pc, #348]  ; (80040ac <bsp_initSPIADIS+0x160>)
 8003f50:       6b08            ldr     r0, [r1, #48]   ; 0x30
 8003f52:       f440 7080       orr.w   r0, r0, #256    ; 0x100
 8003f56:       b5f8            push    {r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, lr}
 8003f58:       6308            str     r0, [r1, #48]   ; 0x30
 8003f5a:       2500            movs    r5, #0
 8003f5c:       6810            ldr     r0, [r2, #0]
 8003f5e:       f240 3607       movw    r6, #775        ; 0x307
 8003f62:       4b53            ldr     r3, [pc, #332]  ; (80040b0 <bsp_initSPIADIS+0x164>)
 8003f64:       f44f 5eb8       mov.w   lr, #5888       ; 0x1700
 8003f68:       f020 000c       bic.w   r0, r0, #12
 8003f6c:       4c51            ldr     r4, [pc, #324]  ; (80040b4 <bsp_initSPIADIS+0x168>)
 8003f6e:       4f52            ldr     r7, [pc, #328]  ; (80040b8 <bsp_initSPIADIS+0x16c>)
 8003f70:       6010            str     r0, [r2, #0]
 8003f72:       6810            ldr     r0, [r2, #0]
 8003f74:       f040 0008       orr.w   r0, r0, #8
 8003f78:       6010            str     r0, [r2, #0]
 8003f7a:       6890            ldr     r0, [r2, #8]
 8003f7c:       f020 000c       bic.w   r0, r0, #12
 8003f80:       6090            str     r0, [r2, #8]
 8003f82:       6890            ldr     r0, [r2, #8]
 8003f84:       f040 0004       orr.w   r0, r0, #4
 8003f88:       6090            str     r0, [r2, #8]
 8003f8a:       6890            ldr     r0, [r2, #8]
 8003f8c:       f040 0008       orr.w   r0, r0, #8
 8003f90:       6090            str     r0, [r2, #8]
 8003f92:       6a10            ldr     r0, [r2, #32]
 8003f94:       f020 00f0       bic.w   r0, r0, #240    ; 0xf0
 8003f98:       6210            str     r0, [r2, #32]
 8003f9a:       6a10            ldr     r0, [r2, #32]
 8003f9c:       f040 0010       orr.w   r0, r0, #16
 8003fa0:       6210            str     r0, [r2, #32]
 8003fa2:       6a10            ldr     r0, [r2, #32]
 8003fa4:       f040 0040       orr.w   r0, r0, #64     ; 0x40
 8003fa8:       6210            str     r0, [r2, #32]
 8003faa:       6b08            ldr     r0, [r1, #48]   ; 0x30
 8003fac:       4a43            ldr     r2, [pc, #268]  ; (80040bc <bsp_initSPIADIS+0x170>)
 8003fae:       f040 0002       orr.w   r0, r0, #2
 8003fb2:       6308            str     r0, [r1, #48]   ; 0x30
 8003fb4:       6818            ldr     r0, [r3, #0]
 8003fb6:       f020 5040       bic.w   r0, r0, #805306368      ; 0x30000000
 8003fba:       6018            str     r0, [r3, #0]
 8003fbc:       6818            ldr     r0, [r3, #0]
 8003fbe:       f040 5000       orr.w   r0, r0, #536870912      ; 0x20000000
 8003fc2:       6018            str     r0, [r3, #0]
 8003fc4:       6898            ldr     r0, [r3, #8]
 8003fc6:       f020 5040       bic.w   r0, r0, #805306368      ; 0x30000000
 8003fca:       6098            str     r0, [r3, #8]
 8003fcc:       6898            ldr     r0, [r3, #8]
 8003fce:       f040 5080       orr.w   r0, r0, #268435456      ; 0x10000000
 8003fd2:       6098            str     r0, [r3, #8]
 8003fd4:       6898            ldr     r0, [r3, #8]
 8003fd6:       f040 5000       orr.w   r0, r0, #536870912      ; 0x20000000
 8003fda:       6098            str     r0, [r3, #8]
 8003fdc:       6a58            ldr     r0, [r3, #36]   ; 0x24
 8003fde:       f020 6070       bic.w   r0, r0, #251658240      ; 0xf000000
 8003fe2:       6258            str     r0, [r3, #36]   ; 0x24
 8003fe4:       6a58            ldr     r0, [r3, #36]   ; 0x24
 8003fe6:       f040 7080       orr.w   r0, r0, #16777216       ; 0x1000000
 8003fea:       6258            str     r0, [r3, #36]   ; 0x24
 8003fec:       6a58            ldr     r0, [r3, #36]   ; 0x24
 8003fee:       f040 6080       orr.w   r0, r0, #67108864       ; 0x4000000
 8003ff2:       6258            str     r0, [r3, #36]   ; 0x24
 8003ff4:       6b08            ldr     r0, [r1, #48]   ; 0x30
 8003ff6:       f040 0002       orr.w   r0, r0, #2
 8003ffa:       6308            str     r0, [r1, #48]   ; 0x30
 8003ffc:       6818            ldr     r0, [r3, #0]
 8003ffe:       f020 4040       bic.w   r0, r0, #3221225472     ; 0xc0000000
 8004002:       6018            str     r0, [r3, #0]
 8004004:       6818            ldr     r0, [r3, #0]
 8004006:       f040 4000       orr.w   r0, r0, #2147483648     ; 0x80000000
 800400a:       6018            str     r0, [r3, #0]
 800400c:       6898            ldr     r0, [r3, #8]
 800400e:       f020 4040       bic.w   r0, r0, #3221225472     ; 0xc0000000
 8004012:       6098            str     r0, [r3, #8]
 8004014:       6898            ldr     r0, [r3, #8]
 8004016:       f040 4080       orr.w   r0, r0, #1073741824     ; 0x40000000
 800401a:       6098            str     r0, [r3, #8]
 800401c:       6898            ldr     r0, [r3, #8]
 800401e:       f040 4000       orr.w   r0, r0, #2147483648     ; 0x80000000
 8004022:       6098            str     r0, [r3, #8]
 8004024:       6a58            ldr     r0, [r3, #36]   ; 0x24
 8004026:       f020 4070       bic.w   r0, r0, #4026531840     ; 0xf0000000
 800402a:       6258            str     r0, [r3, #36]   ; 0x24
 800402c:       6a58            ldr     r0, [r3, #36]   ; 0x24
 800402e:       f040 5080       orr.w   r0, r0, #268435456      ; 0x10000000
 8004032:       6258            str     r0, [r3, #36]   ; 0x24
 8004034:       6a58            ldr     r0, [r3, #36]   ; 0x24
 8004036:       f040 4080       orr.w   r0, r0, #1073741824     ; 0x40000000
 800403a:       6258            str     r0, [r3, #36]   ; 0x24
 800403c:       6c0b            ldr     r3, [r1, #64]   ; 0x40
 800403e:       4820            ldr     r0, [pc, #128]  ; (80040c0 <bsp_initSPIADIS+0x174>)
 8004040:       f443 4380       orr.w   r3, r3, #16384  ; 0x4000
 8004044:       640b            str     r3, [r1, #64]   ; 0x40
 8004046:       61e5            str     r5, [r4, #28]
 8004048:       6026            str     r6, [r4, #0]
 800404a:       6823            ldr     r3, [r4, #0]
 800404c:       4e1d            ldr     r6, [pc, #116]  ; (80040c4 <bsp_initSPIADIS+0x178>)
 800404e:       f023 0338       bic.w   r3, r3, #56     ; 0x38
 8004052:       6023            str     r3, [r4, #0]
 8004054:       6823            ldr     r3, [r4, #0]
 8004056:       f043 0338       orr.w   r3, r3, #56     ; 0x38
 800405a:       6023            str     r3, [r4, #0]
 800405c:       f8c4 e004       str.w   lr, [r4, #4]
 8004060:       6b0b            ldr     r3, [r1, #48]   ; 0x30
 8004062:       4c19            ldr     r4, [pc, #100]  ; (80040c8 <bsp_initSPIADIS+0x17c>)
 8004064:       f443 1300       orr.w   r3, r3, #2097152        ; 0x200000
 8004068:       630b            str     r3, [r1, #48]   ; 0x30
 800406a:       603a            str     r2, [r7, #0]
 800406c:       6839            ldr     r1, [r7, #0]
 800406e:       f000 faab       bl      80045c8 <printf>
 8004072:       4b16            ldr     r3, [pc, #88]   ; (80040cc <bsp_initSPIADIS+0x180>)
 8004074:       4629            mov     r1, r5
 8004076:       2203            movs    r2, #3
 8004078:       601c            str     r4, [r3, #0]
 800407a:       2001            movs    r0, #1
 800407c:       f7fe f90e       bl      800229c <xQueueGenericCreate>
 8004080:       4629            mov     r1, r5
 8004082:       6170            str     r0, [r6, #20]
 8004084:       2203            movs    r2, #3
 8004086:       2001            movs    r0, #1
 8004088:       f44f 4480       mov.w   r4, #16384      ; 0x4000
 800408c:       f7fe f906       bl      800229c <xQueueGenericCreate>
 8004090:       4b0f            ldr     r3, [pc, #60]   ; (80040d0 <bsp_initSPIADIS+0x184>)
 8004092:       2240            movs    r2, #64 ; 0x40
 8004094:       f44f 4100       mov.w   r1, #32768      ; 0x8000
 8004098:       6130            str     r0, [r6, #16]
 800409a:       601c            str     r4, [r3, #0]
 800409c:       6019            str     r1, [r3, #0]
 800409e:       f883 230e       strb.w  r2, [r3, #782]  ; 0x30e
 80040a2:       f883 230f       strb.w  r2, [r3, #783]  ; 0x30f
 80040a6:       bdf8            pop     {r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, pc}
 80040a8:       40023800        andmi   r3, r2, r0, lsl #16
 80040ac:       40022000        andmi   r2, r2, r0
 80040b0:       40020400        andmi   r0, r2, r0, lsl #8
 80040b4:       40003800        andmi   r3, r0, r0, lsl #16
 80040b8:       40026058        andmi   r6, r2, r8, asr r0
 80040bc:       00030416        andeq   r0, r3, r6, lsl r4
 80040c0:       08008ec8        stmdaeq r0, {r3, r6, r7, r9, sl, fp, pc}
 80040c4:       2000c2d0        ldrdcs  ip, [r0], -r0
 80040c8:       00030456        andeq   r0, r3, r6, asr r4
 80040cc:       40026070        andmi   r6, r2, r0, ror r0
 80040d0:       e000e100        and     lr, r0, r0, lsl #2
```

Comment: Using structs across compile domains can lead to failure.  I know it is the current fad but it will pass...

Comment: BTW what is your question?

Comment: It could be a timing restriction on how long it takes the controller to start.  GCC is **NOT** re-ordering in your assembler, if `RCC_AHB1ENR_DMA1EN` is 256 or 0x100.  I would suggest adding a delay between enable and writing.  Addresses of controller memory would help people understand the compiler assembler, unless you expect someone to be intimately familiar with your controller to answer here.  Ie, physical address of `RCC` and `DMA1_Stream3`.

Comment: RCC base address is 0x40023800, DMA1_Stream3 base address is 0x40026058

Also, here is the values used in those structures:
RCC_AHB1ENR_DMA1EN = 0x00200000,
DMA_SxCR_PL = 0x00030000,
DMA_SxCR_MINC = 0x00000400,
DMA_SxCR_TCIE = 0x00000010,
DMA_SxCR_TEIE = 0x00000002,
DMA_SxCR_DMEIE = 0x00000001

Comment: Have you got the cache enabled?

Comment: Does it work with optimisation switched off? Try debugging the disassembly to see what order the registers are being written to. GCC does re-order certain things so it is possible that this is happening. It is hard to relate the assembly above to the fragments of source code!

Comment: Your code looks odd, why it does so many operations for one simple constant expression: from my compiler:  427         `DMA1_Channel1 -> CCR = DMA_CCR_MINC | DMA_CCR_TCIE | DMA_CCR_EN | DMA_CCR_MSIZE_0 | DMA_CCR_PSIZE_0 | DMA_CCR_TEIE | (DMA_CCR_PL_Msk);
08004f7c:   movw    r2, #13707      ; 0x358b
08004f80:   str     r2, [r4, #0]` It looks like instead of defines you have variables. Something is wrong. Add code with debug print call as well. Mix assembly with C code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes after any operation enabling peripheral clock there is a bug in both STM32F4 & F7 micros. There is a small delay needed

I usually use `__dsb();` for it. You can provide this delay (it is described in the errata but not for all affected uC (actually I have not found any unaffected F4 or F7)). I personally use dsb as it advised in the F4 errata, it reminds me about this bug.

> 2.1.5  Delay after an RCC  peripheral clock enabling Description A delay between an RCC peripheral clock enable and the effective
>   peripheral enabling  should be taken into account in order to manage
>   the peripheral read/write to registers. This delay depends on the
>   peripheral mapping: • If the peripheral is mapped on AHB: the delay
>   should be equal to 2 AHB cycles. • If the peripheral is mapped on APB:
>   the delay should be equal to 1 + (AHB/APB  prescaler) cycles.
>   Workarounds
>   1. Use the DSB instructio n to stall the Cortex ®
>   -M4 CPU pipeline until  the instruction is  completed.
>   2.     Insert “n” NOPs between the RCC enable bi t write and the peripheral register writes  (n = 2 for AHB peripherals, n = 1 + AHB/
>   APB prescaler in case  of APB peripherals).
>   3.     Or simply insert a dummy read operation  from the corresponding register just after  enabling the peripheral clock.

Comment: Perfectly right! Thank you very much.

After reading your answer I looked into the STM32F7 HAL and I found that they add a dummy read after setting the DMA1EN bit.